# SwiftUI NavigationLink pops automatically which is unexpected

Tags: ios, navigationlink, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

I am having some issues with a NavigationLink on an iPad with split view (landscape). Here is an example:

[image: screen recording]

Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class MyEnvironmentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var object: MyEnvironmentObject

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Go to FirstDestinationView", destination: FirstDestinationView(isOn: $object.isOn))
        }
    }
}

struct FirstDestinationView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Go to SecondDestinationView", destination: SecondDestinationView(isOn: $isOn))
    }
}

struct SecondDestinationView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
            Text("Toggle")
        }
    }
}

// Somewhere in SceneDelegate
ContentView().environmentObject(MyEnvironmentObject())
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this? An easy fix is to disable split view, but that is not possible for me.

Comment: @Asperi Please explain what's wrong in the code. I don't understand why this is happening. The screen should not pop when toggling the switch, right?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, misread the code - looks like List caching problem.

Comment: @Asperi Just updated the question without using a `List`. Any other ideas what the issue could be?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, here is my investigation results (tested with Xcode 11.2) and below is the code that works.

In iPad `NavigationView` got into Master/Details style, so `ContentView` having initial link is active and process bindings update from environmentObject, so refresh, which result in activating link of details view via same binding, thus corrupting navigation stack. (Note: this is absent in iPhone due to *stack* style, which deactivates root view).

So, probably this is workaround, but works - the idea is not to pass binding from view to view, but use environmentObject directly in final view. Probably this will not always be a case, but anyway in such scenarios it is needed to avoid root view refresh, so it should not have same binding in body. Something like that.

```
final class MyEnvironmentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selection: Int? = nil
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var object: MyEnvironmentObject

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Go to FirstDestinationView", destination: FirstDestinationView())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstDestinationView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Go to SecondDestinationView", destination: SecondDestinationView())
        }
    }
}

struct SecondDestinationView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var object: MyEnvironmentObject

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $object.isOn) {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I understand why this would work. Unfortunately this is not a solution for me. That is because the master view needs to be able to "refresh" when the user interacts with it.

Comment: The code works great. However, the same issue reproduces if I add another NavigationLink which uses EnvironmentObject variables to ContentView. For example, `NavigationLink(tag: 0, selection: $object.selection, destination: EmptyView.init) { EmptyView() }`

Answer (score 5):

When something within `EnvironmentObject` changes, it will render the whole view again including `NavigationLink`. That's the root cause of automatic pop back.

My research on it:

- OK on iOS 15 (seems Apple fixed)
- Still broken on iOS 14
- The reason why "This bug went away when I dropped the @EnvironmentObject and went with an @ObservedObject instead." @Jon Vogel mentioned is ObservedObject is a local state, which will not be affected by other views while EnvironmentObject is global state and can change from any other remote views.

Answer (score 0):

You need can use [isDetailLink(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/isdetaillink(_:)) to fix that, e.g.

```
struct FirstDestinationView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Go to SecondDestinationView", destination: SecondDestinationView(isOn: $isOn))
        .isDetailLink(false)
    }
}
```