# Unexpected SwiftUI behavior with hidden NavigationLink and EnvironmentObject

Tags: swiftui

I'm having trouble with having EnvironmentObject and hidden NavigationLink.

The code is below. It just aims to navigate users from the `ContentView` to the `SecondView` and then to the `ThirdView` using simple NavigationLink while having hidden NavigationLink in `ContentView`. (CatView and DogView are just simple Views holding a Text)

The thing is when the app updates one of the EnvrionmentObject (which is not used for hidden NavigationLink) on the `ThridView`, it navigates me back to the `SecondView`.

```swift
class FlagEnv: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flag = false

    func toggleFlag() {
        flag.toggle()
    }
}

class SelectionEnv: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selected: Selection?

    enum Selection: String {
        case cat, dog
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var flag = FlagEnv()
    @StateObject private var selection = SelectionEnv()

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Hidden NavigationLinks supposed to be triggered by selection
                NavigationLink(tag: .cat, selection: $selection.selected, destination: CatView.init) { EmptyView() }
                NavigationLink(tag: .dog, selection: $selection.selected, destination: DogView.init) { EmptyView() }

                NavigationLink("Go to 2nd view") {
                    SecondView()
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(flag)
        .environmentObject(selection)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        NavigationLink("Go to 3rd view") {
            ThirdView()
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var flag: FlagEnv

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        Button("Toggle Env Flag") {
            flag.toggleFlag()
        }
    }
}
```

For your reference, `_printChanges()` prints the logs in the console as below.

```
// When app launched
ContentView: @self, @identity, _flag, _selection changed.

// When navigated to Second view
SecondView: @self changed.

// When navigated to Third view
ThirdView: @self, @identity, _flag changed.

// When toggle the flag
ThirdView: _flag changed.
ContentView: _flag changed.
SecondView: @self changed.
```

However, if I add `.isDetailLink(false)` to the NavigationLink in the `ContentView` as below, it doesn't happen but not sure why.

```swift
NavigationLink("Go to 2nd view") {
  SecondView()
}
.isDetailLink(false)
```

Do you know why the original issue happen and how can I solve it, and also why the `isDetailLink` changes the behavior?

Comment: You change state object it refreshes body, so rebuild navigation view which destroys previous navigation stack... with `.isDetailLink(false)` stack is flat (only one destination in it, latest replaces previous), so ... something like that. Actually it is long-known behavior (one of corresponding posts https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546127/12299030). And NavigationView has deprecated, so start looking onto NavigationStack

Comment: @Asperi Thanks! First of all, NavigationStack can't be an option for me because my app supports iOS 14 and above. And regarding your suggestion in the other post, I tried exactly your code and it stops working if I add the follwoing code to the ContentView. 

`NavigationLink(tag: 0, selection: $object.selection, destination: EmptyView.init) { EmptyView() }`